# Simple 'drag and drop style' video compressor

Tags: video, compression

Is there any app really simple to compress videos on Mac?

Something like [JPEGmini](http://www.jpegmini.com/mac) for videos (do not resize, just reduce file size).

I just know [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), but it is not the most simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not free, but Apple itself has an app called Compressor.

You can see its information here: [Compressor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/compressor/id424390742?mt=12)

Usually it is used together with Final Cut Pro, but can as well be used standalone.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Macroplant's Adapter](https://www.macroplant.com/adapter/). It has a list of presets and is really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/). I use it quite often and while it offers most of the options of HandBreak (and some it doesn't), it can be a drag-and drop video compressor if your want.